# Self decrease a value in MySQL column each day

Tags: mysql, error-handling

I am new at PHP, but I been doing all I could do to know what went wrong here:

```
$sid = $db->EscapeString($_GET['data']);
    $site = $db->FetchArray($db->Query("SELECT id,cpc FROM `surf` WHERE `id`='".$sid."'"));
    $check = $db->GetNumRows($db->Query("SELECT * FROM `surfed` WHERE `user`='".$data['id']."' AND `site`='".$sid."'"));
    $pr = mysql_query("SELECT premium  FROM users");
        if($site['id'] != "" && $check == 0 && $pr['premium'] = "0"){
        $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `coins`=`coins`+'".$site['cpc']."' WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'");
        $db->Query("UPDATE `surf` SET `visits`=`visits`+'1', `points`=`points`-'".$site['cpc']."' WHERE `id`='".$site['id']."'");
        $db->Query("INSERT INTO `surfed` (user, site) VALUES('".$data['id']."', '".$site['id']."')");
    }
        elseif($site['id'] != "" && $check == 0 && $pr['premium'] != "0"){
        $db->Query("UPDATE `users` SET `coins`=`coins`+ 20 WHERE `id`='".$data['id']."'");
        $db->Query("UPDATE `surf` SET `visits`=`visits`+'1', `points`=`points`-'".$site['cpc']."' WHERE `id`='".$site['id']."'");
        $db->Query("INSERT INTO `surfed` (user, site) VALUES('".$data['id']."', '".$site['id']."')");
    }
}
```

So, basically what I been trying to do is reward the users without Premium with the normal amount of coins and those with Premium with 20 coins each on my Traffic Exchange website. I don't know why but the code above rewards everyone with 20 coins.

Another problem is that the Premium above denotes the Premium days left in a person's account, but that doesn't seem to be decreasing each day. Any way to fix it?

Definitions:

- `surf` contains `id`, `user`, `title`, `cpc` etc. This is the table from where the surf page on my Traffic Exchange pulls the data to be shown. `id` is the siteID, `cpc` = cost per click etc.
- `surfed` contains `siteid` and `userid` to prevent the user from surfing the same site again before 24 hours. Cron deletes the data from this table each day.
- `users` contains `id`, `username`, `coins`, `premium` etc. The user info table.

Comment: Wow... that is a lot of queries.

Comment: Rather than storing the number of days left in a person's account, just store an end date - if you want the number of days left, you can calculate it. This way, you don't need to decrement the count for all users every day - much simpler!

Comment: Also, rather than using a `SELECT` to get a user IDs one at a time, just run an `UPDATE` across your whole user table for the update you want, limited by their user type. (If we can see a definition of your 'surf', 'surfed' and 'users' tables, edited into your question, that would help a lot.)

Comment: I don't get it! I mean, is there any way, I can make the value decrease each day using cron? I don't understand calculating? The problem is that it doesn't decrease, i.e, if a person orders a week's Premium it stays for years.

Comment: @user1928108 You should take halfer's suggestions.  Store an expiry date on 'Premium'.  If the date today is past that expiry date, the user has normal status.

Comment: _I don't understand calculating_. If you store an end date, you don't need to decrease everyone's "days left" count every day. Just compare the end date with today's date, and if the end date is before today, they should no longer be treated as a Premium user. If you want to know the number of days they have left, it's `(end_date - todays_date)`, either in PHP or MySQL.

Comment: @halfer,as I already mentioned I am quite a noob. SO, I don't actually understand how to do that! But, you also haven't answered my first question about everyone getting 20 coins... I've edited the quetion.. Thanks for your help till now!

Answer (score 0):

The first problem that I've spotted is you're trying to determine whether a particular user is a 'premium' one or not. To do this, you have this code:

```
$pr = mysql_query("SELECT premium FROM users");
```

However, that will get the 'premium' column for all users, which isn't very useful. Try changing it to this instead:

```
$pr = mysql_query("SELECT premium FROM users WHERE id={$data['id']}");
```

This assumes that your user ID is in `$data['id']` (which I think is the case from your existing code) and that this array entry can be considered already escaped.

Secondly, you are trying to use the value of `$pr` as a result array, when in fact this is a result handle. To use it, you need to do something like this:

```
$pr = mysql_query("SELECT premium FROM users WHERE id={$data['id']}");
$prData = mysql_fetch_assoc($pr);
$premium = $prData['premium'];
```

Thirdly, you appear to have a database class called `$db`, but you are mixing `mysql_` functions into the code. It *may* be better to use the methods provided on the `$db` class, but since I don't know what class you're using here, it is difficult to advise.

---

Aside: it will help you as a beginner if you supply as much information as possible. You need to assume that people know nothing about your use case - so explain everything, include as much information as you can, whilst keeping it reasonably succinct. What is a "surf page"? What is your "Traffic Exchange"? What class is `$db`? With database questions, in general supply your *full* table definitions.

Also, where you get answers to a question, try applying it to your case, asking for clarification as required. For the most part, people here will be willing to teach you, but not willing to do your work for you. It is in any case not good security practice to offer your server credentials to people on the Internet, unless you are confident they won't damage your files or steal your user database `:)`. Be very careful about this!

As I note in the comments, this sort of question is ripe for debugging. You know that the code is not doing what you want it to, but you are not sure *where* it is failing. The trick therefore is to narrow it down until you find a variable that has an unexpected or wrong value.

For example, see this piece of code (I've wrapped it for clarity - you can do this in PHP):

```
$sid = $db->EscapeString($_GET['data']);
$site = $db->FetchArray(
    $db->Query("SELECT id,cpc FROM `surf` WHERE `id`='".$sid."'")
);
```

Try adding a debug statement thus:

```
$sid = $db->EscapeString($_GET['data']);
echo "Site ID: $sid";
exit();
$site = $db->FetchArray(
    $db->Query("SELECT id,cpc FROM `surf` WHERE `id`='".$sid."'")
);
```

Then, check `$sid` is the value you expect. If it is, great, and move on to the next bit of code. If not, see *why* it is not correct. The next thing I'd try would be something like this:

```
$sid = $db->EscapeString($_GET['data']);
$sql = "SELECT id,cpc FROM `surf` WHERE `id`='" . $sid . "'";
echo "Surf query: $sql";
exit();
$site = $db->FetchArray($db->Query($sql));
```

Here you can check your SQL query is as you expect.

Comment: That still credits every user(whether premium or not) with 20 coins. I am ready to provide you access to my cPanel if thats okay! Or, if its suitable, I can give you the download link to the script! Whichever's better, just let me know. Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: No good news yet. Can I provide you with the PHP script so that you can have a look at it?

Comment: It's better for you to learn how to ask a question here, so other people can help too. If there is more of the script people need to see in order to help you, edit it into your original question. However, before all that, have you done some debugging? For each part of your code, try putting in `print_r($myVar);exit();` to see if the values are as you expect.

Comment: I've added some simple examples of how to debug. Give that a try and let us know how you get on!

Comment: I'll try that later, sir.. I appreciate all the help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Just so you know, it is customary here to +1 if you like an answer, and/or tick ('accept') the best one. Wait a day or so in case other answers come in though, in case other answers arrive.